# Sybase force backward scan

Tags: sql, indexing, sybase, sap-ase, sql-execution-plan

I have a sybase query with an order by clause on an indexed date column.
The index is:

```
create clustered index DATE_IDX on dbo.MY_TABLE ( DATE_COLUMN ASC )
```

I wish the index was:

```
create clustered index DATE_IDX on dbo.MY_TABLE ( DATE_COLUMN DESC, [... some other columns in my ORDER BY clause] )
```

but I can't, since the infrastructure I'm using does not support DESC indexes.

My query works fine if I order by DATE_COLUMN ASC or DESC, but as soon as I add more columns to the order by clause (after DATE_COLUMN) while ordering DATE_COLUMN DESC, I get really bad performance.

The problem becomes obvious when I inspect the query plan.

It should be

```
Nested iteration.
  Using Clustered Index.
  Index : DATE_IDX
  Backward scan.
  Positioning at index end.
```

But instead it is

```
Nested iteration.
  Using Clustered Index.
  Index : DATE_IDX
  Forward Scan.
  Positioning at index start.
```

If I create a DESC index, my problem is solved (it becomes really fast, but I cannot do it in production environment).
Is there a way to force backward scans? Are there other solutions to my problem (other than creating a DESC index)? Thank you.

Comment: You should get the same really bad performance regardless of `ASC` or `DESC`.  Sybase has to sort the data if it is not available in sorted form in the index.

Comment: But it is sorted. I'm using a clustered index. I get good performances with a DESC index (but I cannot use it in production). (I have to create the DESC index with additional columns that are in my order by clause)

Answer (score 0):

what is the value of Sybase configuration Parameter allow backward scans :

```
exec sp_configure "allow backward scans"
go
```

the above code should show the current value , Default is ON but maybe it's turned off on your environment ?